# How do I give the user the choice of programs with which SIM card to call?

Tags: android, android-studio

Wrote a little program, when you click on the number of calls, and all would be well in this tale, but tested it on another phone, and when you just departed from the program, but then I remembered that he had dual sim.Tak how to put that to standard sim card when you run the program was 1 or 2? or given a choice, what would the user chose how the sim card to call him? 
Tried to use getDeviceId (), writes that "Non-static metod ...". 
That part of the code that is used to make a call:

```
final Intent calling1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    call1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            calling1.setData(Uri.parse("tel:5555"));
            startActivity(calling1);
        }
    });
```

On android 4.2.1 by pressing all comes with the application, writes an error, how to fix it too, do not tell?

Comment: Any application built on Android will guarantee only for Single SIM mobiles. Because Android does not support multiple SIMs, at least from the SDK. Device manufacturers who have created multi-SIM devices are doing so on their own. You are welcome to contact your device manufacturer and see if they have an SDK add-on or something that allows you to access the second SIM.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

// set active SIM
i.putExtra("simSlot", SimIndex); // <-------------------

i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));

startActivity(i);
```

Where SimIndex is 0 or 1 for first & second SIM cards, respectively.

On some devices the SIM setting line will be:

```
// set active SIM
i.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", SimIndex)
```

You would probably want to create a fallthrough mechanism that start with the
prior way and, if fails, attempts the latter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: when i set simindex=0(or 1),z see error that putExtra it's non-static method