# Make calls from any SIM card

Tags: android

I was developing an Android App which called a number from a SIM card based upon an `if` condition. The app has to make a call from SIM 1 if one condition is met and from SIM 2 for all other conditions irrespective of what the default SIM is. I went through many of the posts in this site, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

I am currently running my app with the following code

```
// (0 for first sim and 1 for 2nd sim)
callIntent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 1);
```

I have tried one more method as well where

```
private final static String simSlotName[] = {
        "extra_asus_dial_use_dualsim",
        "com.android.phone.extra.slot",
        "slot",
        "simslot",
        "sim_slot",
        "subscription",
        "Subscription",
        "phone",
        "com.android.phone.DialingMode",
        "simSlot",
        "slot_id",
        "simId",
        "simnum",
        "phone_type",
        "slotId",
        "slotIdx"
};

callIntent.putExtra("simSlotName", 1);
```

Both these methods weren't working. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553206/how-do-i-give-the-user-the-choice-of-programs-with-which-sim-card-to-call?rq=1

Comment: I did but no use

Answer (score 1):

The full code is here

```
private final static String simSlotName[] = {
    "extra_asus_dial_use_dualsim",
    "com.android.phone.extra.slot",
    "slot",
    "simslot",
    "sim_slot",
    "subscription",
    "Subscription",
    "phone",
    "com.android.phone.DialingMode",
    "simSlot",
    "slot_id",
    "simId",
    "simnum",
    "phone_type",
    "slotId",
    "slotIdx" };

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "any number"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.force.slot", true);
intent.putExtra("Cdma_Supp", true);
// Add all slots here, according to device.. (different device require different key so put all together)
for (String s : simSlotName)
    intent.putExtra(s, 0); // 0 or 1 according to the SIM card...

// Works only for API >= 21
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    intent.putExtra("android.telecom.extra.PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE", (Parcelable) " here you have to get phone account handle list by using telecom manger for both sim cards: using this method getCallCapablePhoneAccounts()");

context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: above code works fine in many phones. but not working on Vivo V11 Pro 1804 and Vivo Y81. Did you find any new set of keys to this list?

Comment: I get an error around the Parcelable, can you actually show how to use that getCallCapablePhoneAccounts() instead of just giving a description.

Answer (score 0):

The official way is of using this API from [Android 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Marshmallow) (Marshmallow):

```
val uri = Uri.parse("tel:$phone")
val telecomManager = context.getSystemService<TelecomManager>()
val callCapablePhoneAccounts = telecomManager.callCapablePhoneAccounts
val bundle = Bundle()
callCapablePhoneAccounts.getOrNull(sim)?.let { handle: PhoneAccountHandle ->
    bundle.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, handle)
}
if (needToStartWithSpeaker)
    bundle.putBoolean(TelecomManager.EXTRA_START_CALL_WITH_SPEAKERPHONE, true)

telecomManager.placeCall(uri, bundle)
```